# Why nginx not able to serve sites in different locations?

Tags: nginx

I want to use nginx to host some static html which is located in different path on my pc, below is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;


    location /chatserver {
        root /Users/xxxx/gitrepo/chatserver/public;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /test {
        root /Users/xxxx/test/test_site;
        index index.html;
    }
```

The file structure is:

```
Users
  |-xxxx
    |-gitrepo
    |  |-chatserver
    |       |-public
    |          |- index.html
    |-test
       |-test_site
            |- index.html
```

But when I access: `http://localhost:8080/chatserver` or `http://localhost:8080/test`, nginx always responds `404 Not Found`.

If I access: `http://localhost:8080/`, nginx will return the default nginx welcome page.

Why is my configuration not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `alias` instead of `root`.

In your example the URL `/chatserver/index.html` will search the `/Users/xxxx/gitrepo/chatserver/public/chatserver/index.html` (note the "undesired" `chatserver` after `public`!). Check your `nginx`'s logfiles!

See [documentation of root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [documentation of alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).